# How to transpose a vector of strings in Julia 0.6 (in order to plot multiple legends)?

Tags: arrays, plot, julia

In Julia 0.5 you can write:

```
using DataFrames, Plots, StatPlots
df = DataFrame(
    fruit = ["orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple"],
    year = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2010,2011,2012,2013],
    production = [120,150,170,160,100,130,165,158],
    consumption = [70,90,100,95, 80,95,110,120]
)
plotlyjs()
mycolours = [:green :orange]
legend1 = sort(unique(df[:fruit]))
legend2 = legend1'
fruits_plot = plot(df, :year, :production, group=:fruit, linestyle = :solid, linewidth=3, label = ("Production of " * legend2), color=mycolours)
```

where `legend1` is a `2-element DataArrays.DataArray{String,1}` and `legend2` is a `1×2 DataArrays.DataArray{String,2}`.

Now, in julia 0.6 `legend2 = legend1'` is not working any more. You can do instead a `legend2 = reshape(legend1, (1, :))`, but that produces a pretty obscure `1×2 Base.ReshapedArray{String,2,DataArrays.DataArray{String,1},Tuple{}}` that then is not accepted in the `plot()` call.

So, any way in julia 0.6 to produce from a `2-element DataArrays.DataArray{String,1}` a `1×2 DataArrays.DataArray{String,2}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Again, posting on SO helps.. ;-)

I finally got that I can obtain the plot anticipating the string concatenation:

```
fruits_plot = plot(df, :year, :production, group=:fruit, linestyle = :solid, linewidth=3, label= reshape("Production of " * sort(unique(df[:fruit])),(1,:)), color=mycolours)
```

Comment: Alternatively (thanks @daschw git user): `label= "Porduction of " .* reshape(sort(unique(df[:fruit]))`